# Greasemonkey: How to do something when style="display: none;" changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, greasemonkey

I've tried attrchange, waitForKeyElements, and MutationObserver and none of them work for what I'm trying to do (or I don't understand enough to make them work lol) so after 5 hours of trying to figure this out, I give up.

On a minigame on a site I play, at the end a message at the top of the page shows whether you won or lost.  The 'play again' button is at the bottom of the page where you finish the game.  I cannot see the win/lose message without scrolling up so I want to clone that message to lower on the screen like this:

```
$( ".alert alert-success" ).clone().prepend( "#play_again" );
$( ".alert alert-danger" ).clone().prepend( "#play_again" );
```

or

```
$( "#winning" ).clone().prepend( "#play_again" );
$( "#loss" ).clone().prepend( "#play_again" );
```

The html looks like:

```
<div class="col-md-9">

    <div id="winning" class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1" style="display: none;">
        <div class="alert alert-success"> … </div>
    </div>
    <div id="loss" class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1" style="display: none;">
        <div class="alert alert-danger"> … </div>
    </div>
```

After the game:

```
<div id="loss" class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1" style="">
    <div class="alert alert-danger"> … </div>
```

My script runs too soon and I can't find any element to use for waitForKeyElements.  I can't figure out a way to run waitForKeyElements on a style change and when I try I get a silent script failure.

Cloning or moving before they are hidden does nothing...

How in the heck do I make my script run AFTER the 'style' changes? Preferably without polling because my computer is acting wimpy lately... Something like an event listener but for css.

Thanks!

Comment: you can append the whole div to #play_again and then you won't need to intercept the change. you could also use css to scoot the buttons up instead of cloning or moving them.

Comment: I tried that... it didn't work... it didn't show up when the one on top of the page did... I thought it would...

Comment: ok, fair enough. the CSS over-ride idea should still work though, and it's the simplest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this **[plugin](http://techfoobar.com/jquery-style-listener/)** is easy to use , as im not very expert with grease monkey , but im trying to help , anyway , it works such that you can invoke some action upon attribute change such as `display` attr.

this is a simple example :

```
$('#foo').styleListener({

    // the styles that you want to monitor for changes
    styles: ['visibility', 'width', 'height', 'color', 'font-size'],

    // function to be called when a monitored style changes 
    changed: function(style, newValue, oldValue, element) {
        alert(style + ' changed from ' + oldValue + ' to ' + newValue);
    }

});
```

**Edit:**

Digging around we can use an event listener with event "DOMAttrModified" , more info can be found **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)**

**Edit 2**

this [**plugin**](https://github.com/RickStrahl/jquery-watch) uses **[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)** which i believe is a good solution , the interval is just used for old IE browsers ( guess this is not a big issue ) , find an example **[here](http://samples.west-wind.com/jquery-watch/)**

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather not have something that runs in a loop as I have a kinda wimpy computer..

Comment: @KatCox me neither i didnt notice it works on loop thought that was event listener , let me find a better solution.

Comment: DOM modification events are deprecated due to their performance impact, you should use mutation observers instead.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I recently read that DOMAttrModified is depreciated?  Lol... it's still a good answer though and maybe my Firefox is old enough that it'd work.

Comment: @KatCox im so sorry , i was just busy and didnt really search well , i love helping people though , i guess i should free myself a bit and search well.

Comment: @the8472, maybe you should write up an answer with mutation observers so I can figure out what I did wrong trying to use them... and you ninja'd me on the depreciated thing... I type too slow

Comment: i really was in a rush that i even havent seen the notice in MDN page to use MutationObserver instead !

Comment: Firefox 24 works well with DOMAttrModified (which is good since I can't figure out that plugin)... My question is... what is the newest version of firefox that it works with?

Comment: Good, that means I can share the script...  Thank you!